# Typescript: How to access and default not existing object properties?

Tags: typescript

How to access and default not existing object properties?

In this example typescript complains about `fooBar[foo]` -
`Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type '"fooBar"' can't be used to index type '{ readonly foo: "bar"; readonly bar: "foo"; }'.
  Property 'fooBar' does not exist on type '{ readonly foo: "bar"; readonly bar: "foo"; }'`

What is typescript way to achieve this functionality?

```
const fooBar = {
    foo: 'bar',
    bar: 'foo'
} as const

const foo: 'foo' | 'fooBar' = 'fooBar';

const op: 'foo' | "bar" | 'default' = fooBar[foo] || 'default';
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEAhAhgJxgXhgbwFAyHyIBcMA5AEbrkA0BR1aZ5CI5eAvjChDKJCh48A6MRAs25GAB8KbVGmnZWiReQDcw0bBAAHSYmlyARExOyKAEwCmcFAFcANlGXjFAbTYBdWXPK29s6uGkA)

Comment: Could you add details what's the real use case?

Comment: @AlekseyL. I have a use case where I need to remap values because on local API I have 2 values representing same value for 3th party API. e.g local API: `stone-cut`, `stone` => 3th party API: `stone`. [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgSwDZQKYCcByBDAtqiGAXhgG8AoGKmAYQEEAVAUQHEB5AJQE0B9AGQCMALhgByYNjQBzEOgCeg0QBpK1AMoM2mJjxoBVBiNHRwqALTAArlFHkAvjGyFQkKOXIvoMCAAdUwBGwkGidUADFsYFQoAFlsH2IyVSoAbUQUDBx8CAA6DS0dfQYAXSMTMFRbBycYTzcPcC90VABHSwRmgBMIqKhCEhTk+GQ0LDwCHPpmdm5+ARVqYYyx7LzNbV0DFWKc3HiACnTRrNRiAD5vPwCgkIhwyOi4nzSRzPHimAB+T6Xj8YBKADcQA)

Answer (score 0):

The value of `foo` is either "foo" or "fooBar", so when you say `fooBar[foo]` the compiler complains, because "fooBar" is not in `keyof typeof fooBar`.

The only way to make the compiler stop complaining is to lie to it like so:

```
type FooBar = typeof fooBar
const op: FooBar[keyof FooBar] | 'default' =
    fooBar[foo as keyof FooBar] || 'default';
```

Again, it's a lie, because in your case you know that `foo` is either "foo" or "fooBar" and you know that "fooBar" is not one of the keys in `fooBar`.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't like this solution. I would rather use `type any` for `foo`